# Invalid Requirement ERROR while installing a local git repository of Django

Tags: python, django, pip

I am trying to install the development version of Django in a virtual environment. A local repo lives inside:

```
"C:\Users\AARYAN DEWAN\Desktop\localdjango\django"
```

I first created a virtual environment inside

```
"C:\Users\AARYAN DEWAN\Desktop\virualenvs"
```

using

```
py -m venv .\djangodev
```

Then I activated it.

Now when I try to follow the [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/contributing/) and install the local django repository inside this virtual environment, using

```
py -m pip install -e C:\Users\AARYAN DEWAN\Desktop\localdjango\django
```

it throws up an error saying:

> ERROR: Invalid requirement: 'DEWAN\Desktop\localdjango'
>       Hint: It looks like a path. File 'DEWAN\Desktop\localdjango' does not exist.

I have tried replacing the path with this:

```
py -m pip install -e C:\Users\AARYAN DEWAN\Desktop\localdjango
```

but it still does not work!?

What should I do?

Comment: Is the trailing comma really there or it was wrongly copy pasted into the question?

Comment: It is wrongly copy-pasted

Comment: Please don't use the [git] tag for things that merely happen to involve a Git repository (as the [tag:git] info says).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess would be that it's because of the white space in `C:\Users\AARYAN DEWAN\Desktop\localdjango\django`.

I would try the following instead:

```
py -m pip install -e "C:\Users\AARYAN DEWAN\Desktop\localdjango\django"
```

Comment: IT WORKED! THANK YOU SO MUCH! Can you please tell why did you add those " "? Do I have to add them every time I pip install something as there is a space in the path?

Comment: Otherwise it's interpreted as two different items on the command line. In this case I guess maybe it's trying to install two different things `C:\Users\AARYAN` and `DEWAN\Desktop\localdjango\django`, which obviously don't actually exist. Yes, usually (almost always) white spaces have to be _escaped_ or enclosed in quotes (depends on the context). In your case, I would recommend to create a new user account without a white space. And generally avoid as much as possible creating directories or files with white spaces, especially if you want to work with the command line.

Comment: Yeah, I do get it now. But the problem is that windows is not allowing me to change the name of that folder for some reason. There is no "rename" option coming when i right click on c:\Users\Aaryan Dewan.

Comment: I don't think you can rename your user directory so easily (look it up). You have to rename your user profile, and I believe it's not that simple either (look it up). I'd recommend creating a new user account, or do your development work from say: "C:\workspace".